# Is it possible to connect with estimote beacon without using location permission

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I have an `estimote beacon`, i want to display a `notification`, when user comes in `beacon range.`

I was checking `estimote beacon's` android integration document, and found out that it requires `location permission.`

`Estomote official app` also does not work, if location permission is not granted.

My question is how to make beacon work without asking location permission, or if beacon does not work without location permission then what's the reason of using beacon, or am i missing something very important.

Comment: `estimote beacon` how does it connect to the phone?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko : I have `Estimote` sample app, it detects the beacon position, if its in device range.

Comment: that does not answer my question: `how does it connect to the phone?` Using what?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko : via bluetooth, beacon transmits Bluetooth signals, which contains its UDID, if app has any knowledge of the received UDID, it can display personalized notification to the user.

Comment: Bluetooth search requires location permission. Therefore you can't do Bluetooth search without location permission. Location does not have to be enabled for the search, but you have to request the permission

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko : oh ok, Thanks for pointing this out. Have you used beacon in any of your app? If yes, then why we need this if we still need to ask location permission from users. If i know user's location then i know where user currently is or i can use geo-fencing. Why beacon?

Comment: firstly, it was not always that way. Before Android 6 you did not need the location permission to use Bluetooth scan. And the reason it was added is exactly same as your aim - you can get user's location using bluetooth. Therefore the user has to explicitly grant you permissions to track his location (even via bluetooth). Beacons can be used for other purposes then just general geolocation. You for example can use them for indoor navigation, etc. Also the **location itself doesn't have to be ON to search for Bluetooth devices**

Comment: Thanks @VladyslavMatviienko: Thanks, This clears things alot, so beacons just ask location permission to use bluetooth, but they don't actually require any location services to perform their operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 6+ requires an app to obtain either COARSE_LOCATION or FINE_LOCATION permission at runtime in order to detect Bluetooth LE beacons or do Bluetooth LE scans at all.  **Without the permission, the OS blocks beacon detections.**  This is not an Estimote-specific issue -- it applies to scanning for any Bluetooth LE device.

This requirement was added to protect the privacy of users.  The theory is that a runtime permission dialog makes it clear to a user that the app is accessing the user's location and ensures the user is aware of this and consents to the practice.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung, so beacons just ask location permission to use bluetooth, but they don't actually require any location services to perform their operation.

Comment: and the only advantage i am seeing of using `beacon` over `geo-fencing` is that it gives  more concise user location then geo-fence..As far as functionality, i think i can achieve all the features beacon offering via geo-fencing.

Comment: Detecting beacons also do require Location to be turned on  in Android 6+.  If it is disabled, all BLE scans return no results, including beacons.  The other advantage over geofencing is that they work deep inside buildings where GPS signals cannot reach.